# HyperLinks not working (redirection while using pretty url with htaccess)

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, hyperlink, url-rewriting

Here is my php code(qs.php). This file contain pretty url links.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php  
    $file = 'qs1'; //this is a php file qs1.php
    $id = '12345678'; //testing ID
    $complete_url = $file."/".$id;

    ?>
    <a href ="<?php echo $complete_url;?>"> This is a test link </a>

</body></html>
```

This link appear link this - http://localhost/qs1/12345678

QS1 is a php file (qs1.php).

QS1.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>QS1 file</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#"><img src="images/blog/girl.png" class="img-circle" alt="" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/blog/girl2.png" class="img-circle" alt="" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/blog/girl3.png" class="img-circle" alt="" /></a>

</body></html>
```

Below is the htaccess code.

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Everything is working fine. My link is working properly. 
http://localhost/qs1/12345678 link is accessible by this. I am able to access the page. In my current page wherever i use this code(**#**). I can say other links on that page.

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/blog/girl.png" class="img-circle" alt="" /></a>
```

It is redirecting to localhost only instead of passing the same to current page.

Not sure what i am missing.

Comment: I put some html code of qs1.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This is not a htaccess or url redirection issue. 
It is JavaScript issue. # is used for jquery. 
My function was not working properly.

So, it was redirection to localhost.
I found this link which help me understand what is going wrong.
[What does <a href="#" class="view"> mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160758/what-does-a-href-class-view-mean)

Here is why it was not directing.
I used # in jquery. Like below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#").click(function(){
    alert("Hello!");
});
```

$("#") isn't a valid selector. So, i will have to use anchor tags.

Below is the working code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $(".vote").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Hello!");
});
```

event.preventDefault() used because i am using

Hope this help someone.

I got help to find out the issue by DelightedD0D. 
You can see the complete answer on this link.

[bind click event to anchor tags on my page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419636/jquery-javascipt-not-working?noredirect=1#30419675)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want : if file or directory not exit than redirect

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: did you try with '!'?, i added lost signs just some mins ago

Comment: yes, i did that. But no luck. I tried with ! and without.