# bind click event to anchor tags on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my javascript file code. Script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#").click(function(){
    alert("Hello!");
});
```

And here is my php code.

```
    <html>
    <head>
Some codes are here
    </head>
    <body>
    Some php codes are here to get value from database
    <script src="script.js"></script>
        <span><a href="#" class="vote" id="<?php echo $cid; ?>" name="up"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></a> <?php echo $up; ?> </span>

             <span><a href="#" class="vote" id="<?php echo $cid; ?>" name="down"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i></a> <?php echo $down; ?> </span>

        <span><a href="#" class="vote" id="<?php echo $cid; ?>" name="favorite"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></a> <?php echo $fav; ?> </span>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I am calling script file in body due to my design. I can't call it in head section.

Issue is when i click on above link corresponding to # (up,down, fav). It take me to index file. I am testing Hello in alert box. But it is not working.

Any advice what i am missing.

Comment: Change `$("#").click(` to `$("a").click(`. Just # is not a selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#` in `$("#")` means and `id` should follow. Like if your element's id were "myElement" you would write `$("#myElement")`.

But, since you dont know your ids adead of time, id use the `vote` class you already have instead like `$(".vote").click....`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".vote").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Hello! My id is: " + this.id);
      });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><a href="#" class="vote" id="someId1" name="up"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>Some sontent</a></span>

<span><a href="#" class="vote" id="someId2" name="down"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>Some sontent</a> </span>

<span><a href="#" class="vote" id="someId3" name="favorite"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>Some sontent </a> </span>
```

Comment: I have one doubt. .above code is working fine but after i click OK on alert. It redirect to index file.

Comment: My bad, I forgot `event.preventDefault();` which is needed because the element is a link and a link's default behaviour is to navigate to the `href` url

Comment: Now its stopped working after using event.preventDefault();. Page is redirecting to index.

Comment: Did you notice that this line changed too `$(".vote").click(function(event) {` ?  You'll need to add `event` there also, I should have been more clear.

Comment: Got it. I didn't seen that earlier. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I didn't get why it downvoted. strange :(. Did i asked something stupid?

Comment: Most likely due to the vague question title `Jquery/javascipt not working` . Just now I edited this to  `bind click event to anchor tags on my page` which is much more descriptive of the issue. It's important for question titles to have meaning and be descriptive so that when other users search they find questions related to their issue. Imagine if all questions about javascript were titled `Jquery/javascipt not working`. As for the donvoters, some users will edit, some will downvote and not say why.... : )

Answer (score 7):

`$("#")` isn't a valid selector. If you want to capture clicks on anchors it should be `$('a')`;

Comment: @404 This will work, but keep in mind that in practice you'll probably want to target elements more directly. It's unlikely you want ALL anchors on the page

Answer (score 1):

In order to get all the anchor tags you should use $("a") instead of $("#"). Use $("#abc") in order to get a tag with id abc. Use $(".def") in order to get tags with class def.

Answer (score 1):

Use attr name at the selector and call directly the function you want... $('a') is so generic

try to use

```
$("a[name='up']").on('click',function(){
    alert("Clicked up!");
});

$("a[name='down']").on('click',function(){
    alert("Clicked down!");
});

$("a[name='favorite']").on('click',function(){
    alert("Clicked down!");
});
```

Comment: DelightedD0D answer is more detailed. I will vote up.